# How to set path for background image in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am having a problem to specify the path of the background logo in ASP.NET Core.

My physical path of the logo file is:

```
c:\iasp\webapplication1\logo.jpg
```

Logo can display in browser if the below path is used:

```
<a href="#" class="img logo rounded-circle mb-5" style="background-image: url(C://iAsp//WebApplication1//wwwroot//js//logo.jpg)
```

but, when I use `~/logo.jpg`, no logo is displayed:

```
<a href="#" class="img logo rounded-circle mb-5" style="background-image: url(~/logo.jpg)
```

What is the correct path to call out the logo file for the url?

Thanks

Comment: Place the files in the webroot folder as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0 - The web root path defaults to {content root}/wwwroot.

Comment: Where'd you put the logo tho? another folder after `wwwroot`?

Answer (score 1):

The background image in ASP.NET Core should inside the wwwroot. The wwwroot should be the default path for your image.

For example, if the path is `C://iAsp//WebApplication1//wwwroot//js//logo.jpg`

Then, the a tag background image should be:

```
<a href="#" class="img logo rounded-circle mb-5"    style="background-image: url(/js/logo.jpg">aaa</a>
```